# How to clean MSWord document with regex or in C#

Tags: ms-word, format

I would clean part of MS Word documents with Regex or C# function.

Example :

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="">Grâce au kit d’aspiration, le nettoyeur haute pression peut aspirer de l’eau et être alimenté à moindre coût à partir d’eau de récupération (récupérateur d’eau de pluie, citerne, etc.). Tuyau de 5m de long avec clip de fixation et dispositif de nettoyage de filtre. SérieK3-4 aspiration jusqu’à 50 cm de profondeur, série K5-6 jusqu’à 1 m et série K7jusqu’à 1,50 m. Compatible avec les nettoyeurs haute pression K3 à K7.<span style="color: black; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt;"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

Expected result :

Grâce au kit d’aspiration, le nettoyeur haute pression peut aspirer de l’eau et être alimenté à moindre coût à partir d’eau de récupération (récupérateur d’eau de pluie, citerne, etc.). Tuyau de 5m de long avec clip de fixation et dispositif de nettoyage de filtre. SérieK3-4 aspiration jusqu’à 50 cm de profondeur, série K5-6 jusqu’à 1 m et série K7jusqu’à 1,50 m. Compatible avec les nettoyeurs haute pression K3 à K7.

Thanks for your help

Comment: In other words, remove the HTML elements?

Comment: You can just use Find and Replace for that. Check the box for "Use wildcards", set the Find text to `\<*\>` and leave the Replace text blank.

Comment: Safer to use: Find = \<[!\<]@\>